# css dom manipulation Angular component to html-css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm having trouble doing dom manipulation on angular/node.js/ using typescript in my visualcomponent.html 
        
        working

in this case the second inline styling works and displays with the h1 in blue color
but when i try to add strings of  within the innerhtml like so... 
inside my visual.component.ts:

```
  htmlVariable:string = "<h1 style = 'color:blue; margin- 
    left:30px;'> not working</h1>"
  constructor(private _httpService: HttpService, private _route: 
  ActivatedRoute,
  private _router: Router) { }
```

is there any other way i can manipulate the css? i couldn't find a way to do it through the vision.component.css like i can do it through inner html on the .html file
thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried adding "encapsulation" in the component to "ViewEncapsulation.None"?

Comment: hi niral thanks for the help the encapsulation did work in the sense that, if i already had a div in my visual.component.html with an ID i can use styles on it through my visual.component.ts with success. I still can't manipulate the css in my visual.component.ts when i do a innerHTMl append where i add another div into it. i believe it is giving me a sanitize error

Comment: nevermind it did work! i kind of do not understand why but when i use ID's it sanitizes the id and doesnt apply it when it hits the html part after the component.ts. After i switched to classes when i insert divs into the html it works and is logged onto the inspect and the sanitize error goes away! thank you for showing me the viewencapsulation

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) for direct access to DOM elements in Angular.

```
import {Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
export class AppComponent implements ngOnInit {

constructor(private _httpService: HttpService, private _route: ActivatedRoute, private _router: Router, private _elementRef : ElementRef) { }

ngOnInit(): void
{
  this.ModifyDOMElement();
}

 ModifyDOMElement() : void
 { 
   let domElement = this._elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`#someID`);
   domElement.style.color = "Red"; //Apply CSS Properties here
 } 

}
```

Your HTML:

```
<h1 id="someID"></h1>
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out kunai!, this solution kept on giving me an error saying the style does not exist. however, i did find an alternative solution using viewencapusulation. once again thanks for commenint

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the same using `custom pipe` using [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer).

```
import { Component, NgModule, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Pipe({ name: 'safeHtml'})

export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform  {

  constructor(private sanitized: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value) {
    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }
}
```

and when you need this variable to bind in the view part as `innerHTML` do use this pipe and your style should works as expected-

```
<div [innerHTML]="htmlVariable | safeHtml"></div>
```

PS: I assume you must be imported pipe in your main module before using.

For more information in detail, you can read out here

- https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#members

Comment: hey pardeep thanks for helping me solve this problem i tried to do other methods before i tried this one but i think this would have solved the problem for using ID's thanks you for your comments!

Comment: Glad to know :)